# builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable

Tags: python-3.x

Estou fazendo um programa para encontrar o maior primo mas estou com o seguinte erro: `builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Entrada' referenced before assignment`
O que poderia ser? A variável `Entrada` foi definida, não estou entendendo....

```
def Maior_Primo(X):
    X = N = Entrada
    Primo = 0
    RestoPrimo = 0

    while Entrada > 0 : 
        if Entrada == 0:
            MP ( 0 )

        else:
            while N > 0 :
                Divisão = Entrada % N  
                if Divisão == 0:
                    RestoPrimo = RestoPrimo + 1
                N = N - 1

        if RestoPrimo == 2 :
            if Entrada > Primo:
                Primo = Entrada
                Entrada = Entrada - 1
        return Primo

print(Maior_Primo(2))
```

Comment: Na primeira linha da função você definiu que X será igual a N que será igual a Entrada. Qual é o valor de Entrada nesse ponto do código? A variável ainda não existe dentro da função; por acaso criou ela fora?

Answer (score 0):

Bom, deu certo agora, ficou assim.

## coding: utf-8

def maior_primo(x):
    Entrada = x
    N = x
    Primo = 0
    RestoPrimo = 0

```
while Entrada > 0 : 
    if Entrada == 0:
        MP ( 0 )

    else:
        while N > 0 :
            Divisão = Entrada % N  
            if Divisão == 0:
                RestoPrimo = RestoPrimo + 1
                N = N - 1
            else:
                N = N - 1

        if RestoPrimo == 2 :
            if Entrada > Primo:
                Primo = Entrada
                Entrada = Entrada - 1
                N = Entrada
                RestoPrimo = 0
            else:
                Entrada = Entrada - 1
                N = Entrada
                RestoPrimo = 0

        else:
            Entrada = Entrada - 1
            N = Entrada
            RestoPrimo = 0
return( Primo )
```

Comment: O que mudou? O que estava errado? Por que dava erro?